# Make line thicker in a matplotlib time series 'spaghetti' plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Thanks for reading.

I have a plot and would like to make the latest year in my dataset stand out. My data is just one long time series, so I want to plot YoY comparisons, so I pivot it, then plot it.

The first block of code runs and gives me roughly what I am after (without the latest year standing out), then in the second block of code I try to make my latest stand out (which technically works) but the colour is different, doesn't match the legend and can even be the same colour as another year.

I can see the old series in the background. I think I am creating another plot and putting this on top, but how can I select the original line for the latest year (in this case 2018) and just make that stand out?

Or is there a better way to do this whole process? 
Any tips on code, formatting or anything would be much appreciated, I am very new to this!

Thanks so much!

13sen1

---

FIRST BLOCK

```
# import
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create fake time series dataframe
index = pd.date_range(start='01-Jan-2012', end='01-01-2019', freq='M')
data = np.random.randn(len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['Data'])

# pivot to get by month in rows, then year in columns
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.month, columns=df.index.year, values='Data')

# plot
df_pivot.plot(title='Data by Year', figsize=(6,4))
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[firstblockresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6KYz.png)

SECOND BLOCK

```
# import
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create fake time series dataframe
index = pd.date_range(start='01-Jan-2012', end='01-01-2019', freq='M')
data = np.random.randn(len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['Data'])

# pivot to get by month in rows, then year in columns
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.month, columns=df.index.year, values='Data')

# plot
df_pivot.plot(title='Data by Year', figsize=(6,4))
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()

# plot the thicker last line
# **************** ERROR HERE *************************
plt.plot(df_pivot.iloc[:, -1:], lw=4, ls='--')
# **************** ERROR HERE *************************
plt.show()
```

[secondblockresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XCDc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the line of the last year thicker. Because columns are sorted, it will be the last line in the axes (index `-1`).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create fake time series dataframe
index = pd.date_range(start='01-Jan-2012', end='01-01-2019', freq='M')
data = np.random.randn(len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['Data'])

# pivot to get by month in rows, then year in columns
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.month, columns=df.index.year, values='Data')

# plot
ax = df_pivot.plot(title='Data by Year', figsize=(6,4))
ax.get_lines()[-1].set_linewidth(5)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

ax.figure.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks so much for your quick and perfect response.